# Better way to handle 404 page not found in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React app and i'm trying to figure out a better way to redirect to 404 page not found when user hits a wrong path.
Basically my application has a navbar with three main routes (Home, Content, Permissions) and a default redirect to render a route that displays 404 page not found:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/content" component={Content} />
  <Route path="/permissions" component={Permissions} />
  <Route path="/not-found" component={PageNotFound} />
  <Redirect to="/not-found" />
</Switch>
```

My problem is with the **/Permissions** route because this one has many subroutes to display multiple configuration pages and i need to fetchData with a hook, so if the user goes to a wrong path it needs to wait for data fetching before being redirected to page not found:

```js
const Permissions = () => {
  const {isFetchingData} = usePermissionsData();

  if(isFetchingData) {
    return <Loading />;
  } 

  return (
    <div className={styles.permissions} >
      <div className={styles.leftMenu} >
        <LeftMenu />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.content} >
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/permissions" component={PermissionsWelcome}
          <Route path="/permissions/users" component={UsersPermissions}
          <Route path="/permissions/content" component={ContentPermissions}
          <Route path="/permissions/dashboard" component={DashboardPermissions}
          <Redirect to="/not-found" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So my question is if it exists a better way to redirect the user to a page not found without needing to wait for the data fetching? (something that i consider is a waste of proccesing).
Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A better way" can be subjective, but to help with the ***objective*** issue of needing to match a route *before* checking permissions then I suggest inverting control. By this I mean you should create a custom `Route` component that will be matched first *then* check the permissions. It's not clear if your code snippet is a simplified version, but I assume the hook probably also determines if a user has permission to access the current route/resource. If there is an additional check for this then you can conditionally render a `Route` with the current props or you can render a `Redirect` to "bounce" the user off the route since they are missing required permission(s).

Example:

```
const PermissionRoute = props => {
  const {isFetchingData} = usePermissionsData();

  if(isFetchingData) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return <Route {...props} />;
};
```

Permissions

```
const Permissions = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.permissions} >
      <div className={styles.leftMenu} >
        <LeftMenu />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.content} >
        <Switch>
          <PermissionRoute path="/permissions/users" component={UsersPermissions} />
          <PermissionRoute path="/permissions/content" component={ContentPermissions} />
          <PermissionRoute path="/permissions/dashboard" component={DashboardPermissions} />
          <PermissionRoute path="/permissions" component={PermissionsWelcome} />
          <Redirect to="/not-found" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Main Routing

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/content" component={Content} />
  <Route path="/permissions" component={Permissions} />
  <Route path="/not-found" component={PageNotFound} />
  <Redirect to="/not-found" />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

React router is priority based, The top lines/top routes have more priority than others, you can just add a route with a normal react page with no path attribute, Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Main from './Main'; // Main component
import NotFound from './NotFound'; // Create a not found component

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route component={NotFound} /> // this must be placed atlast.
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```